# UMN MapServer cutting off bitmap symbols during generating print output from LIDS client

Tags: mapserver

I have similar issue as here: [Preventing clipped labels from QGIS Server WMS in Leaflet JS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346467/preventing-clipped-labels-from-qgis-server-wms-in-leaflet-js)

But I have issue with cutting of symbols on border of tiles not with labels.

Here is a picture with my situation:
[image]

Red line is boundary of two tiles and as you can see pictures with navigation signs are cut off.
I tried all what I found on whole Internet but without success.

How do I change setup of UMN MapServer to gave me good result?

Comment: You cannot resolve the issue on the server side. Your client must make oversized requests so that the symbol is included in both the left side map and right side map. When the clients trims these oversized images into 256x256 tiles the symbols get clipped correctly. If you make 256x256 sized requests directly the point with the symbology is within one tile but not within the other. Straight forward solution is to disable tiling on the client. In OpenLayers this is called as Single Tile mode.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I asked our GIS supplier for their statement ;-)